# Realm database object seems empty, but then isn't

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am using [Realm](https://realm.io) for a small, simple project. I'm using the latest version of the framework (compiled from Github yesterday) and the current AppStore version of Xcode with Swift 2.1.

I am handing a Realm database object over from one view controller to another via a segue in `prepareForSegue()`, in order to edit it (and fill out the current values).

Somehow, there seems to be a problem with the object in the target view controller. When I simply `print()` the object in the target view controller (either in `viewDidLoad()` or any of the methods I plan to use it in), the object is properly shown in the console like so:

```
Object {
name = asdf
value = 8
}
```

and so on.

If I try to access the values (even in the previous or next line) and assign them to another variable like `myValue = objectToEdit.value` I get 0.

Debugging the code by stepping into it with breakpoints shows the object in the debugger with all values empty ("") or 0, depending on the type. Still, somehow Strings are grabbed out of it for some reason, I can access and print them with `myString = objectToEdit.name`, while the debugger shows `name = (String) ""`, claiming it's empty.

The same behavior already occurs when I get the database object out of the database in the first view. The immediate thought would be, that the values are indeed 0 and only the strings were saved, but the `print()` method says otherwise.

Can anybody explain this odd behavior and maybe show me where I overlooked something? I now suspect it's some internal problem of the framework, but I'm not sure. I'll of course update with more code or answer questions, if needed.

Comment: Please post more code.

Comment: Have you tried to open the realm file with the realm browser to inspect the db?

Comment: @netshark1000 I have tried and am able to open and inspect the db, it seems to be fine. All values are there and what they are supposed to be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the problem when I noticed that the values, oddly enough, were the "default" values I put in the definition of the model.

For some reason, I did not use the `dynamic` declaration on some of the properties, like so:

```
class myObject: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    var value = 0
}
```

This caused the new Object that was created in the view controller to have these standard values and I always got the 0, but on the other hand could get the correct Strings.

Adding `dynamic` to the variable declaration fixed my problems.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Damn ... same mistace here. Thank you very much

Comment: you saved me some hours of life!

Answer (score 0):

You will need [the LLDB plugin](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/plugin/rlm_lldb.py) to see correct values while debugging your code.
Install it as advised in the first code comments or just execute the script below:

```
mkdir -p ~/Library/Application\ Support/Realm
wget -O ~/Library/Application\ Support/Realm/rlm_lldb.py https://raw.githubusercontent.com/realm/realm-cocoa/master/plugin/rlm_lldb.py
touch ~/.lldbinit
grep -q "rlm_lldb.py" ~/.lldbinit || echo "command script import "~/Library/Application Support/Realm/rlm_lldb.py" --allow-reload" >> .lldbinit
```

Comment: Trying that now, but I'll have to install wget first, which seems to be difficult for me (SSL stuff acting up). Thanks, will report back.

Comment: I executed your script, but no difference. Looking at the code and the debugger output again, I find that I can access the String values, but the Integer values remain 0.